# .Net MAUI ListView ignores FlexLayout options and gets height of window

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

When a ListView is present in FlexLayout (column) it ignores the flex height configuration in a strange way: it is spaced correctly in relation to others, but cuts off some items from ItemSource at the end when the size is too small.

Here's an example for list of 20 items:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the code for the inner flex:

```
        <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                Direction="Column"
                JustifyContent="Start"
                AlignContent="Start"
                >
        <Label Text="This is spaced correctly"
               FlexLayout.Shrink="0"
               />
        <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  FlexLayout.Grow="0"
                  FlexLayout.Shrink="1"
                  
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Content}"
                              Detail="{Binding FromUserName}"
                              DetailColor="Aquamarine"
                              />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label Text="This is spaced correctly"
               FlexLayout.Shrink="0"
               />
    </FlexLayout>
```

As you can see, 5 items are impossible to view

How can I fix the scroll to go to the end of the list so that I can view all items in a collection?

Comment: Temporary fix, I threw out all FlexLayout and used on Grid with Auto sizes

Comment: *"cuts off some items from ItemSource at the end when the size is too small"* I looked at the images, but I still don't understand what that means. What exactly is "cut off"? When the size (of what?) is too small. It sounds like ListView doesn't quite know how much vertical height it should use.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I ment that out of 20 items only 15 are visible on the screen, event if I extend the window or go fullscreen